# Are A51 proposals valid Gaming ads?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Are Community Promotion ads a valid place for Area 51 proposal ads? Here's why I think it would be a valid candidate ad:

1. SE Podcast #6 was all about the gamification of Stack Exchange.
2. Area 51 proposals are games as well
3. Games are valid candidates for Community Promotion ads

If 1 and 3 are true, then, assuming 2, then Area 51 proposals are valid candidates for Community Promotion Ads.

Thoughts?

Comment: [I actually kinda have a thread to collect these kinds of mini-questions about the process](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1903/community-promotion-ads-explanation-and-feedback), just so you know.

Comment: @GraceNote - Did not realize that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know I brought up the other thread as where this would be easier to address, but I'll nevertheless provide an answer for you.

Video games are valid candidates for Community Promotion ads. Not just games in general - there's a whole lot of games that exist that are not a valid topic for this site, or its ad space.

Stack Exchange is game-like. But each of these sites is not a video game. Nor are the proposals that correspond to them. So your attempted logical proceeding doesn't quite work out in the favor of allowing them.

Let's thus *remove* the bed of attempted logic, and just address the underlying question of "Should we have Area 51 proposals on the Community Ads?".

The answer is **no**. The ad space *already* promotes Area 51 proposals in its rotation. We don't need to be redundant.

Comment: Thanks! Going to accept in a few minutes.

Comment: Caveat: If there were a serious Video Gaming related proposal on A51 that you thought you could do justice to with a better ad than the standard rotation, well then... maybe. But the fact is that any video game proposal on A 51 should *probably* just be folded in here at the moment, unless it's attempting to tackle one of our explicitly off topic fields.

Comment: @LessPop I was originally going to write my answer as "If the proposal is video-game related, then it would fit", up until I thought about the whole redundancy aspect. Then I figured, it's just too redundant to bother pointing it out. That was my take, though.